# How to change color icon in Materialize?

Tags: css, materialize

I use css framework Materialize.css
I don't understand where past color in my HTML icon

```
<i class="large material-icons">note_add</i>
```

I have tried `cyan darken-4`

```
<i class="large material-icons cyan darken-4">note_add</i>
```

But nothing succeeded, I need exactly change color icon.
How to make it?

Comment: Have you defined the classes `cyan` and `darken-4` in your CSS?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this by adding a class to your icon like below-

```
<i class="large material-icons icon-blue">note_add</i>
```

And then in your CSS stylesheet, you can define the color for the `icon-blue` class

```
i.icon-blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Your icon color will then be changed. Hope this helps!

Comment: While this does work, you're not taking advantage of the built in Materialize classes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37537496/6402953

Answer (score 89):

Add the class of "cyan-text" & "text-darken-4" to the .

```
<i class="large material-icons cyan-text text-darken-4">note_add</i>
```

Comment: This works in 2022 and the accepted answer below no longer works. Change `cyan` to your color of choice. For example: `large material-icons purple-text text-darken-1`

Answer (score 20):

It's easy, I'll show you an example:

```
 <i class="material-icons large red-text">room</i>
```

Just enter the name before the text (**red**-text)

Answer (score 8):

I got an example with using the "style" attribute.

```
<pre></td><td class="col-sm-2"><i class="little material-icons" style="color:blue">search</i></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to  [Materialize documentation](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) you can access their direct css attributes.

- .input-field input[type=text]:focus + label or similar
- Class or ID modifier
- Using   [materialize's color palette](https://materializecss.com/color.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you asking that you want to change icon colour in Materialize CSS.
Same was my Question But i have Find the ans....that

```
<i class="material-icons red-text" >home</i>
```

This Code will change the icon Color and if we want to give its background color just change it in **custom.css**

```
.class {background-color:red;}
```

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to use Jquery**

- This will change color of all the material icons

> `$(".material-icons").css("color", themeColor);`

- This will change color of the material icons inside an  element eg input field

> `$(".input-field>.material-icons").css("color", themeColor);`

**Live Demo**

See the Pen [Materialize CSS Change Theme Color](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/EXoPRq/) by Hitesh  Sahu ([@hiteshsahu](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).